# Android Studio modify bytecode before converting to dex

Tags: android, compilation, bytecode, dex

I want to change the bytecode of the compiled source code of an android project before it is packed into the final APK file. As far as I know, the source code is compiled to java bytecode and then converted to DEX using `dx` in Android Studio. Can I somehow modify the java bytecode before it is converted to DEX and then packed into the APK file? Somehow hook in between the java bytecode to dex conversion step using gradle? It should be possible somehow, as many android projects are obfuscated using ProGuard, which normally uses JAR files as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for AGP's [Transform API](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/transform/Transform).
You can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApPlFsbBznw) a decent API introduction, and [here](https://medium.com/grandcentrix/transform-api-a-real-world-example-cfd49990d3e1) an example for using it.

Comment: Is there a way of only running the transformation when exporting an APK file? Right now my transformation is run for every build, but I only want to transform it when it is exported.

Comment: @AuraLee By "exporting an APK file" you mean "building a release APK"? If yes, you can probably filter it by overriding [Transform#applyToVariant](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/transform/Transform#applytovariant), which says `Whether this transform should be applied to a given variant.`.